# Why is the Bean validator throwing ConstraintViolationException on the not nullable but auto-generated id field?

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, bean-validation

ENTITY CLASS :

```
public class MyUser implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;


    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    // other attrs and getter-setters


    public MyUser() {
    }

    public MyUser(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public MyUser(Integer id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

USAGE CODE :

```
MyUser myuser = new MyUser();
myuser.setName("abc");

try {
    em.persist(myuser);
} catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
    System.out.println("size : " + e.getConstraintViolations().size());
    ConstraintViolation<?> violation = e.getConstraintViolations().iterator().next();
    System.out.println("field : " + violation.getPropertyPath().toString());
    System.out.println("type : " + violation.getConstraintDescriptor().getAnnotation().annotationType());
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
INFO: size : 1
INFO: field : id
INFO: type : interface javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
```

**ENVIRONMENT :**

JDK 6 u23
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1-b41 (has bean-validator.jar)
NetBeans IDE 7.0 Beta 2

**QUESTION :**

Does anyone has suggestion on why is the Bean validator throwing this exception on the not nullable but auto-generated id field? What is the right approuch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With IDENTITY generation, the entity is first inserted in database with a null identifier, and a query is executed afterwards to get the value of the generated ID. So, at insert time, your ID is null and thus violates the NotNull constraint.

Comment: So what is the right way for passing the bean validation successfully? Setting the `Id` field with the temporary/dummy value is not an appropriate approach i think.